# SQL Pivoting for Attribution Modelling

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am working on transforming some SQL data that looks like below: (This table is referred as [OGtable]

```
   Date            SiteKey UserKey ConversionNo Ranking    Type      TimeDiff
18/01/2016 19:51    eBay      a     1             1     Impression     NULL
18/01/2016 19:55    eBay      a     1             2     Impression       0
19/01/2016 20:26    eBay      a     1             3     Conversion     1475
```

My goal is to transform it into something like this:

```
SiteKey UserKey ConversionNo    Type    TimeDiff    Path                   CaseNumber
eBay      a        1         Impression    0      Impression1,Impression2   1testaa
eBay      a        1         Conversion   1475    Impression2,Conversion    1testaa
```

I have made attempt to pivoting but I have only pivot the whole user path instead, namely:

```
  CaseNumber                              Path
1test1000204837065964386a   Impression1.Impression2.Z_Conversion3
```

So please could anyone help me with implementing the pivot function correctly (or achieve this through other means?)

Many thanks!

Will

My failed script is as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT casekey, (
    SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT '.' + CONCAT(inq.Type,inq.Ranking)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                Ranking,
                CONCAT(ConversionNo,'test',UserKey,'a') AS casekey,
                CASE WHEN EventTypeKey in (4) THEN 'Z_Conversion' ELSE 'Impression' END AS Type
            FROM #OGtable
            GROUP BY
                Ranking,
                CONCAT(ConversionNo,'test',UserKey,'a'),
                CASE WHEN Type in ('Conversion') THEN 'Z_Conversion' ELSE 'Impression' END 
        ) inq
        WHERE inq.casekey = outq.casekey FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')), '&amp;', '&')) AS Nodes
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(ConversionNo,'test',UserKey,'a') AS casekey,
        CASE WHEN Type in ('Impression') THEN 'Impression' ELSE 'Conversion' END AS Type
    FROM #OGtable 
) outq
```

Comment: Perhaps GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Nope it is still giving me the full path :(